# How to combine messages for specific conditions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is the validation code I have written which validates whether the username and password has been entered individually.

```js
$('form').validate({
    messages: {
        username: " Please enter a username.",
        password: " Please enter a password.",
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(".error-message");
    }
});
```

How do I display a combined message if both username and password are not entered?
Eg: `Enter a username and a password.`

Comment: I don't believe you can with this library. All errors are listed separately. I'm not aware of any other library that could do this either, as the generation of the combined error message would take a lot of complex logic to implement for every language with very little benefit.

Comment: Your request will not work well with this plugin.   Each field gets one message at a time for each rule.  You're asking for one single message for all fields and rules simultaneously.  If you only have two fields, you'd be best off just writing a custom validation script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from your code that you're using the jQuery Validation plugin you could do something like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("usernameAndPassword", function(value, element) {
        return $('#username').val().length || $('#password').val().length;
}, "Please enter a username and password.");

$('form').validate({
  rules: {
    username: {
        usernameAndPassword: true,
        required: {
            depends: function(){
            return $('#password').val().length;
          }
        }
    },
    password: {
        required: {
            depends: function(){
            return $('#username').val().length;
          }
        }
    }
  },
  messages: {
    username: {
        required: "Please enter a username."
    },
    password: {
       required: "Please enter a password."
     }
  },
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.appendTo(".error-message");
  }
});
```

This adds a custom validator called `usernameAndPassword` that only fires when neither `username` or `password` are filled in. The required validation on both `username` and `password` is defined to only run when the other one is present, to allow `usernameAndPassword` to take over otherwise.

Comment: Nice thinking. But the problem is that it evaluates the message object just once. So whatever the value is for username or password for the first time, it gets displayed for every other case.

Comment: @pranjal Good spot! Please see updated solution. Also here: https://jsfiddle.net/u8x32q0e/2/

Comment: Why not just use the `showErrors` option to suppress the default messages and construct a single message based on the error map array?

Comment: @Sparky - sure, that's another approach. Post it as an answer.